# What does this line of code means in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Someone please give me a rough meaning of this code

```
render json: {:status => 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render function in rails does the heavy lifting of rendering your application content for use by a browser or client. You can text, JSON, XML, html.erb and others. Now adding json after render will send everything in json format. Like following example will send user information in your response

```
@user = User.first
render json: @user
```

Same we can send text

```
render html: "<h1>Hi this is html</h1>"
```

or we want to send xml

```
render xml: @user
# or
render xml: {:status => 1}
```

Now second part is actual hash where you define status as a key and value is 1 you can create hash like

```
hash = Hash.new(status: 1)
render json: hash
```

This will send all user information in json format.
but your code is making content in directly inline

```
render json: {:status => 1}
# or
render json: {status: 1}
# or
render json: {name: 'my name', age: 23, status: 1}
```

But this is data being sent if we want to send status code we can use

```
render json: {:status => 1},
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the formats, You can use it with Ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

It means that it is returning json.
This is the returned value and you can use it the same way as you can use any json code:
{ status: 1 }